# Position:absolute misaligns div in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, html, css-position

Position: absolute used for a div misaligns the div in Internet Explorer. But works well in Mozilla Firefox and Chrome. Can anyone suggest workaround?

Code

http://jsbin.com/uxerus/15/edit

Comment: Maybe this: http://jsbin.com/uxerus/20/edit  ,seems to work in IE7+

Comment: Yep. But what happens is when this hidden div is shown, it moves all other elements below it, downside in Internet Explorer. I used z-index as well. No effect. Can u check this? http://jsbin.com/uxerus/44/edit

Comment: i'm looking at jsbin.com/uxerus/44/edit using ie9, but fail to understand the problem (besides that you should add a background color to the hidden div)

Comment: In IE8-10 it is shown ok. The problem is only in IE7 (tested it in IE developer tools-F12). The #content should be placed absolutely right below the inputbox, not on its right side. How to make it look the same in all browsers?

Comment: Stano, the solution suggested by roberkules works. :) In my page, i have to calculate the top position value dynamically and set the CSS. Thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to wrap the first input and the hidden div in another div, setting the "wrapper's" `position` to `relative`. Then position the hidden div `absolute` including the `left` and `top` css property.

For a start, see http://jsbin.com/uxerus/56/edit

Should be something like:

css:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

div.first {
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 298px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #fff;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="input" name="input" value="First div" />
    <div id="content" class="first">
        <span>option 1</span>
        <span>option 2</span>
        <span>option 3</span>
        <span>option 4</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. its working. So, i need to set the top attribute value dynamically after calculating the position :) Thanks!!

Comment: `top: 100%` works in ie9+, chrome, firefox but apparently has some issues on ie7/8, but might work somehow.